# Read Memory Memory Mapped File C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, windows, memory-mapped-files

I am trying to share a structure coming from C++ to C# using memory mapped file. So far I managed to write on the file, but I am unable to read the content in C#.

1. SendData in C++

```
struct Bus_1553 // this is the structure to send
{
    string name;
    int directions; 
};

struct Bus_1553* p_1553; // set the pointer to it
HANDLE handle; // create the handle


// here we define the data to send
string name = "IFF";
int directions = 3;

bool startShare() // Open the shared memory
{
    try
    {
        handle = CreateFileMappingW(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, sizeof(Bus_1553), L"DataSend");
        p_1553 = (struct Bus_1553*) MapViewOfFile(handle, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, sizeof(Bus_1553));
        return true;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return false;
    }

}


int main()
{

    if (startShare() == true)
    {

        while (true)
        {
            if (p_1553 != 0) // populate the memory
            {  

                p_1553->name = name;
                p_1553->directions = directions;
            }

            else
                puts("create shared memory error");
        }
    }
    if (handle != NULL)
        CloseHandle(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

2. Trying to read in C#

```
namespace sharedMemoryGET
{
    class sharedMemoryGET
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        public unsafe struct Bus_Data_1553
        {
            public string name;
            public int directions; // which directions used
        }

        public static MemoryMappedFile mmf;
        public static MemoryMappedViewStream mmfvs;

        static public bool MemOpen() // open the mapped file
        {
            try
            {
                mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("DataSend");
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

        public static void readData()
        {
            if (MemOpen())
                {
                    using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor())
                    {
                    accessor.Read(0, out Bus_Data_1553 a);
                    Console.WriteLine(a.name);
                    Console.WriteLine(a.directions);
                    }
                }
            
        }
    }
}
```

When a string is present in the structure to share, I have the following error:
The specified Type must be a struct containing no references.

When I remove the string and share only the int directions, i get a value of 0. Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: Simply put, a C++ `std::string` is not a C# `string`.  The `struct` you're passing is not trivially-copyable due to having `std::string` as a member.  In additon, `sizeof(Bus_1553)` does not do what you think it does.  If the `std::string` had a thousand characters, the `sizeof(Bus_1553)` won't change, as `sizeof` is a compile-time value, not a runtime value.

Comment: The general problem you're trying to solve is known as _serialization_ (or perhaps sometimes _marshalling_). Basically, you'll have to devise some sort of common data format. Maybe that could just be ensuring `Bus_1553` is a standard layout struct, and then you could use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` on the C# side.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie If you have an answer, please put it in the answer section.

Comment: (Got the right Paul this time!)

Comment: Right, as in the below comments, I moved to `char name[128]` and the relative marshalled string in C# `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string name;`. However I still get `The specified Type must be a struct containing no references. Parameter name: type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with what's wrong with the C++ version. I'll bold this to make sure nobody ever passes over this, it's very important: **NEVER WRITE POINTERS TO DISK**

`std::string` is a wrapper around a pointer (2 pointers actually) that handle allocation and reallocation for you as needed. You absolutely cannot write them to a "file" anywhere, you must write the contents of those pointers instead.

One simplistic way (and prevalent in C) to do this is to simply define a buffer large enough to hold your data and then use as much of it as needed:

```
struct Bus_1553 // this is the structure to send
{
    char name[128];
    int directions; 
};
```

To write to `name`, use `strcpy_s` or your OS equivalent.

Now once you write this structure in C++ to your shared file, reading it in C# is about letting the system (the marshaller) decode that soup of bytes into useful managed objects. You do this by using attributes on your structure and field definition:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct Bus_Data_1553
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string name;
        public int directions; // which directions used
    }
```

Also you don't need `unsafe` for this if you use the marshaller properly.

Comment: To be clear... **NEVER WRITE POINTERS TO DISK** isn't in bold capital letters because it'll make your computer explode or something. It's in bold capital letters because it doesn't work and Blindy knows this and s/he's feeling frustrated.

Comment: It'll make your program explode when you read it later and try to dereference it. I'm not sure what point you're trying to make here.

Comment: I don't think it's bad enough to deserve that formatting. **NEVER USE GETS TO READ INPUT FROM THE NETWORK** is okay, but using it for *this* seems excessive.

Comment: Noted, you write pointers to disk, everyone else (including the OP once he fixes this) will handle writing working software.

Comment: I tried to go for marshal has you suggested, but I still get the following error `The specified Type must be a struct containing no references.
Parameter name: type` . Now I can actually share numbers when no character or string is present in the code, however the error arises when i set `char name[128]` and the relative marshalled string in C#. I also wrote the name as ` strcpy_s(p_1553->name, "IFF");`

Comment: You need to invoke the marshaller, not the `struct` version of the mapped file accessor. First get the structure size (`Marshal.SizeOf<Bus_Data_1553>()`), then read that many bytes from your file, then use `Marshal.PtrToStructure()` to get your actual structure. Because the latter requires a pointer, you need to `stackalloc` a temporary buffer of the same size and copy the byte data into it (since the accessor doesn't have an overload for pointers).